# How to calculate average of salary using minimum salary and maximum salary columns

Tags: mysql

To elaborate, i have a job post table with company name, designation , min salary, max salary, min experience , max experience etc.

For a concerned role i am trying to give out average salary and experience .
I wanted do list out the company name(xxx) with role database developer offering average sal and average experice.

```html
 
declare user_details cursor FOR
   select up.role,ur.years,ur.month,upd.current_ctc from user_registration ur 
   left join user_personal_details upd on upd.registration_user_id=ur.iduser_registration
   left join user_projects up on up.employee_id=ur.iduser_registration
   where ur.iduser_registration=p_userID;
  open user_details;
  fetch user_details into v_role,v_exp_years,v_exp_months,v_current_ctc;
  #select v_role,v_exp_years,v_exp_months,v_current_ctc;
  set v_experience= concat(COALESCE(v_exp_years,0),'.',COALESCE(v_exp_months,0));
  #select v_experience;
   BLOCK2: BEGIN
    declare jobs_list cursor for
     select jobid,cr.company_name,jp.max_salary from job_posts jp
     join client_registration cr on cr.idclient_registration=jp.idclient_registration
     where jp.designation=v_role
     and v_experience between jp.min_experience and jp.max_experience  
     group by jp.jobid order by jp.createdon limit 5;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;
     OPEN jobs_list;
     set v_result_joblist='';
     set v_result_role_list='';
     jobs_list_loop: LOOP
     FETCH FROM jobs_list INTO v_jobID,v_company_name,v_max_salary;

      IF v_finished=1 THEN LEAVE jobs_list_loop;        END IF;
      set  v_result_joblist=concat(v_result_joblist,v_jobID,'-',v_company_name,'-',v_max_salary,',');
 
       if(v_result_role_list is null or v_result_role_list='') then 
        set v_result_role_list= v_company_name;
       else                        
        set v_result_role_list=concat_ws('-',v_result_role_list,v_company_name);
       end if;
        BLOCK3: BEGIN
         declare role_wise_jobposts cursor for
          select jp.designation,max(jp.max_salary),min(jp.min_salary),max(jp.max_experience),min(jp.min_experience) from job_posts jp
          join client_registration cr on cr.idclient_registration=jp.idclient_registration
          where cr.company_name=v_company_name
          group by jp.designation order by jp.createdon;

          DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finish = 1;

          OPEN role_wise_jobposts;
           role_wise_joblist: loop
           FETCH FROM role_wise_jobposts INTO v_role_list,v_max_salary,v_min_salary,v_max_exp,v_min_exp;
                
           IF v_finish=1 THEN                LEAVE role_wise_joblist;              END IF;
           set v_result_role_list=concat_ws(',',v_result_role_list,concat('_',v_role_list),v_max_salary,v_min_salary,v_max_exp,v_min_exp);
          END LOOP role_wise_joblist;
           set v_finish=0;
           set v_result_role_list=concat_ws('-',v_result_role_list);
          CLOSE role_wise_jobposts;
           #select v_result_role_list;
        END BLOCK3;

       #select v_result_role_list;
    END LOOP jobs_list_loop;

   END BLOCK2;
 close user_details;
 select v_result_joblist UNION select v_result_role_list;
END
```

Comment: Please share some table data with us.  It strikes me as strange to be storing max and min values.

Answer (score 0):

Make a query like this:

```
SELECT avg(col1 + col2)
FROM test
WHERE uid=5;
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82193/24/0)

Comment: select avg(min_salary+max_salary), min_salary,max_salary from job_posts group by jobid

Comment: Hi Mayank thaks for the reply   select avg(min_salary+max_salary), min_salary,max_salary from job_posts group by jobid This is not returning me correct result